# (Wiring) RPi 4B laptop keyboard

Tags: wireless, pi-4, keyboard, wiring

**NOTE:** Not that I've chosen a few wired keyboards, *I'll accept an answer that explains HOW to (easily) wire a keybard to the pi - it cannot obstruct the use of a small fan powered by the GPIO.*

---

I'm planning out an RPi 4B 3d-printed laptop. I'm trying to make it considerably smaller than most "normal" laptops while keeping the keyboard effectively usable with all fingers at once, like on a full-size laptop (I'm thinking *roughly* 10"). I'm still considering using a wireless keyboard, but it would need to be charged separately. How would I, and how hard would it be, find a (wired) keyboard (plentiful and cheap) and wired it directly to the Pi? Possibly using GPIO? What's the easiest way?
Thanks!

p.s. - I don't have any coding experience. I've never really soldered either, but I heard that it's easy to learn and do. I'm trying to keep this project on the cheap and easy side (yet those two terms never seem to come together :D )

Examples:

-[wired](https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-usb-accessories/products/adafruit-miniature-keyboard-microcontroller-friendly-ps-2-and-usb) (*perfect* size)

-[wireless](https://chicagodist.com/products/10-bluetooth-keyboard-black?variant=3679867437086&currency=USD&utm_campaign=gs-2019-09-24&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2uXDs8rN5gIVbxitBh1EZgzZEAkYBiABEgLg9PD_BwE) (a bit bigger, but workable)

Comment: Your question is: "what if I found a keyboard that can do what I want?" What answer do you expect? Just use it.

Comment: probably easier to use a compact USB keyboard.

Comment: @ingo - sorry, I meant more like "how and how hard". I'll edit the post.

Comment: @Jasen you mean *wired* USB, right (as opposed to wireless with USB reciever)? Definitely going with something around 80% of full scale or less (not too small though). I also definitely want the final product to be in laptop form, keyboard within.

Comment: yes, wired USB. much easier that writing your own keyboard driver, and getting it ti talk to the kernel

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I have no coding experience. My biggest concern is connecting it to the pi, then I can compare that hassle to using a wireless via USB keyboard and see if its worth it. For wired, the first link seems like the **perfect** size. And for wireless, I might push it to 10" with the other one - its physical structure is perfect for laptop projects. (see links added to post, comment too long)

Comment: Cheap:Fast:Right  Pick any two.

Comment: (See top of post)